# Remove objects from an ArrayList based on a given criteria

Tags: java, arraylist

I would like to remove an element from an `ArrayList` in Java if it meets a certain criteria.

ie:

```
for (Pulse p : pulseArray) {
    if (p.getCurrent() == null) {
        pulseArray.remove(p);
    }
}
```

I can understand why this does not work, but what is a good way to do this?

Comment: Not only will this fail to work, but even if it did work it would have terrible performance. It's an O(n^2) algorithm because you have to check every element of the array up to the one you are removing. The optimal algorithm is O(n).

Comment: @MarkByers "check every element of the array" is O(n), why do you think this is O(n^2)?

Comment: @jlordo: `list.remove(object)` is an O(n) operation. It gets executed O(n) times because it's in a loop. That gives O(n*n).

Comment: @MarkByers Thank you. I thought `remove(Object)` is O(1), but Documentation proves your point.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You must use an `Iterator` to iterate and the `remove` function of the iterator (not of the list) :

```
Iterator<Pulse> iter = pulseArray.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
  Pulse p = iter.next();
  if (p.getCurrent()==null) iter.remove();
}
```

Note that the [Iterator#remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) function is said to be optionnal but it *is* implemented by the ArrayList's iterator.

Here's the code of this concrete function from ArrayList.java :

```
765         public void remove() {
766             if (lastRet < 0)
767                 throw new IllegalStateException();
768             checkForComodification();
769 
770             try {
771                 ArrayList.this.remove(lastRet);
772                 cursor = lastRet;
773                 lastRet = -1;
774                 expectedModCount = modCount;
775             } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
776                 throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
777             }
778         }
779 
780         final void checkForComodification() {
781             if (modCount != expectedModCount)
782                 throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
783         }
784     }
```

The `expectedModCount = modCount;` line is why it won't throw an exception when you use it while iterating.

Comment: Technically, the enhanced-for-loop _is_ using an iterator.  Can you give an example of what he'd have to do?  Also, it should be noted that not all iterators will actually implement the remove method, and would throw a 'not implemented' exception.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Yes but the internal ArrayList's iterator does implement it.

Answer (score 44):

You can use [Collection::removeIf(Predicate filter)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) (available from Java8 onwards), here is a simple example:

```
final Collection<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2));
list.removeIf(value -> value < 2);
System.out.println(list); // outputs "[2]"
```

Comment: Don't use this if you want to support the old APIs. Crashed for me with a NoClassDefFoundError on 4.4.

Comment: @Sagar, I added a hint about this.

Answer (score 5):

No need to use iterator. With **Java 8** (streaming and filtering capability and lambdas) you can accomplish it using one line.
For eg. the required code that does the operation you specified will be :

```
pulseArray = pulseArray.stream().filter(pulse -> pulse != null).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You can also use `Objects::nonNull`.

Comment: shouldn't it be `... -> pulse.getCurrent() != null)...`

Answer (score 3):

When you are **removing the element** from the **same list**, the index gets disturbed. Try little differently as below:

```
  for (int i=0; i < pulseArray.size(); i++) {
     Pulse p = (Pulse)pulseArray.get(i);
     if (p.getCurrent() == null) {
        pulseArray.remove(p);
        i--;//decrease the counter by one
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks It worked fine for my lower API version source. For higher versions -> removeIf works as charm.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement interface Predicate overriding abstract method *boolean test(T);*

Use *removeIf(Predicate p)* method to remove all matching elements from your
list.

For example:

```
List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
bookList.add(new Book(101, "bookname1"));
bookList.add(new Book(102, "booknamelong2"));
bookList.removeIf(new LongBookNames())

public class LongBookNames implements Predicate<Book> {

  @Override
  public boolean test(Book book) {
    return book.getBookName.length() >10;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alterative to using an iterator, you can use the [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) collections library.  This has the advantage of being more [functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) (if you are into that sort of thing):

```
Predicate<Pulse> hasCurrent = new Predicate<Pulse>() {
  @Override public boolean apply(Pulse input) {
    return (input.getCurrent() != null);
  }
};

pulseArray = Lists.newArrayList(Collections2.filter(pulseArray, hasCurrent));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't alter a collection that you're iterating through using methods on the collection. However, some iterators (including iterators on `ArrayList`s) support a `remove()` method that allows you to remove methods in the order that you're iterating.

```
Iterator<Pulse> iterator = pulseArray.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  Pulse p = iterator.next();
  if (p.getCurrent() == null) {
    iterator.remove();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below one is used when Single ArrayList have multiple types Objects and one object have count == 0 then it removed from *pulseArray*

> **Constants.java**

```
public class ViewType {
    public static final int PULSE = 101;
    public static final int HEARTBEAT = 102;
}
```

> **BaseModel.java** (This is Base Model)

```
public interface BaseModel {
    int getViewType();
}
```

> **PulseModel.java** (which implements with BaseModel)

```
public class PulseModel implements BaseModel {

    @Override
    public int getViewType() {
        return Constants.ViewType.PULSE;
    }

    @SerializedName("PulseId")
    @Expose
    private String pulseId;
    @SerializedName("Count")
    @Expose
    private String count;
}
```

> **Remove PulseModel object from *pulseArray* in which Count = 0**

```
pulseArray.removeIf(
     (BaseModel model) -> {
         boolean remove = false;
         if (model instanceof PulseModel) {
              remove = (((PulseModel) model).getCount() == 0);
              if (remove) {
                 //Success
              }
         }
         return remove;
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove elements from **ArrayList** based on a *condition* or *predicate* or *filter*, use **removeIf()** method. You can call **removeIf()** method on the **ArrayList**, with the predicate (filter) passed as argument. All the elements that satisfy the filter (predicate) will be removed from the ArrayList.

```
arraylist.removeIf(element -> (Objects.equals(element.getId(), id)));
```

Answer (score -2):

Using an Iterator would give you the power of modifying the list while iterating through the arraylist