# List java do not work on loop

Tags: java, oop, for-loop

I have a list of items and in a `for loop` i'm trying to compare this list but the list make `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`.

Out of the `for loop` the list has 4 items (0,1,2,3) but in the for have only 3 (0,1,2) when I try to access the last item an exception is raised.

```
List<Relatorio> relatorios = new RelatorioDao().listaTudoEmpresa(userWeb.logado);
        for(int i = 0; i < relatorios.size(); i++){
            if(!contem(relatorios.get(i))){
                relatorios.remove(i);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Past the exception stack trace here!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove objects from an ArrayList based on a given criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316629/remove-objects-from-an-arraylist-based-on-a-given-criteria)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not remove items from non-iterator loop.

Consider doing this instead

```
for( Iterator<Realtorio> iter = realtorios.iterator( ); iter.hasNext( ); )
{
   Relatorio cur = iter.next( );

   if(!contem(cur)){
      iter.remove( );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because when you remove the element, you make the list size smaller, thus shortening the loop.

Use the dedicated list iterator when you want to remove elements while iterating, it is safe for this operation :

```
    Iterator<Relatorio> it = relatorios.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
        if (...) {
            it.remove();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do a delete on an item in a list as you are iterating through it. You must use the remove that is on the iterator to do so.
[See This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573661/deleting-all-buttons-dynamically/15574047#15574047).