# My app crashes when entering into an activity which uses Firebase Auth & Database

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

My app crashes every time I use intent to start this activity, the activity allows people to enter some details for registering themselves, and creating an account with an email and password for login, using Firebase Auth & Database.
package com.example.jamsecure;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
   EditText email, pw, mob, pwr, fname;
   Spinner loc;
   ProgressBar progressBar;

   private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_register);
        progressBar=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        email=findViewById(R.id.temail);
        pw=findViewById(R.id.tpw);
        mob=findViewById(R.id.tcn);
        loc=findViewById(R.id.tl);
        pwr=findViewById(R.id.tpwr);
        fname=findViewById(R.id.tfn);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        findViewById(R.id.br).setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(mAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null){
            //handle it
        }
    }

    private void registerUser(){
        final String em=email.getText().toString().trim();
        final String name=fname.getText().toString().trim();
        String password=pw.getText().toString().trim();
        String password_re=pwr.getText().toString().trim();
        final String phone=mob.getText().toString().trim();
        final String location=loc.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
        if(name.isEmpty()){
            fname.setError("Please Enter Full Name");
            fname.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(em.isEmpty()){
            email.setError("Email Required");
            email.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(em).matches()){
             email.setError("Enter Valid Email");
             email.requestFocus();
             return;
        }
        if(password.isEmpty()){
            pw.setError("Enter Password");
            pw.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(password_re.isEmpty()){
            pw.setError("Enter Password Again");
            pw.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(phone.isEmpty()){
            mob.setError("Please Enter Contact Info");
            mob.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(location.isEmpty()){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Please Select Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            return;
        }
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(em,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    User user = new User(name,em,phone,location);
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                            .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                           if(task.isSuccessful()){
                               Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Registration Successful" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                               Intent i = new Intent(Register.this,MainActivity.class);
                               startActivity(i);
                            }
                           else{
                               Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Unable To Register",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.br: registerUser();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

There is no error displayed in the logcat but there is a warning in the java console.

```
Method 'onClick(android.view.View)' is never used
```

Comment: Does this answer your question???https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316629/remove-objects-from-an-arraylist-based-on-a-given-criteria

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove objects from an ArrayList based on a given criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316629/remove-objects-from-an-arraylist-based-on-a-given-criteria)

Answer (score 0):

You must implement `View.OnClickListener`:

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
```

and add `@Override` to your onClick method.

Answer (score 0):

Make your class to implement View.OnClickListener, then add an @override to your onClick Method in the code.

```
 public class Register extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnCLickListener {
//your code here
}

    @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.br: registerUser();
                    break;
            }
    }
```